How to get the browser view file link of a file using Dropbox python API?
I am using the python api for dropbox and my question is the same as this one except I would like to get a link which shows the image in the browser. Not a link which downloads the files.
So I have a FileMetaData object and I would like a link (like one starting with dropbox.com...) which opens the image in the browser. Not a preview link. It looks like this in the browser

How can I do this?
the link is made up of:
dropbox.com/scl/fi/[random_letters_numbers]/[file_name]?rlkey=[random_letters_numbers]&e=2&st=[random_letters_numbers]
I also do not want this link to expire.

to create the link you use the following:
dbx.sharing_create_shared_link_with_settings(myFileMetaDataObj.path_display)
however this will cause an error if you have already created a link for it.
To check whether a link exists or not use:
dbx.sharing_list_shared_links(entry.path_display)

For information on how to modify shared links for different behaviors, such as direct file access, refer to: https://help.dropbox.com/share/force-download

@Greg while this link is great maybe i'm missing something obvious but I haven't been able to easily find "translation" commands for different http API calls

I'm not sure I understand your comment. If you have another question, post another question with the relevant details.

I was just saying the link you sent did not help me understand the answer to my question.

The link I shared addresses the part of your question where you said you want "to get a link which shows the image in the browser. Not a link which downloads the files". For example, by using the raw=1 parameter, you could get direct file access.

I understand that but it does not address how to do it specifically using the python SDK

The Dropbox SDKs themselves do not provide functionality for modifying URL parameters, nor are they needed to do so. You can and should use standard URL libraries to modify URLs, whether or not you also happen to be using a Dropbox SDK.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
